# why is my glsl compute shader not compiling

Tags: glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm attempting to add a compute shader to my vulkan application. My compute shader source is pretty simple for now. It just copies its input SSBO to its output SSBO:

```
#version 320 es

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObjectTest {
    uint num_segments;
} ubo;

layout(std140, binding = 1) readonly buffer verticesSSBOIn {
    vec3 posIn;
    uint vert_typeIn;
    uvec4 mirrorsIn;
    vec3 other_posIn;
};

layout(std140, binding = 2) buffer verticesSSBOOut {
    vec3 posOut;
    uint vert_typeOut;
    uvec4 mirrorsOut;
    vec3 other_posOut;
};

layout (local_size_x = 256, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main() 
{
    uint index = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;  

    if (index < ubo.num_segments) {
        posOut[index] = posIn[index];
        vert_typeOut[index] = vert_typeIn[index];
        mirrorsOut[index] = mirrorsIn[index];
        other_posOut[index] = other_posIn[index];
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to compile it with glslc, I get this error:

```
$ make
~/opengl/vulkan/shaderc/build/glslc/glslc -fshader-stage=compute comp.glsl -o comp.spv
comp.glsl:29: error: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
comp.glsl:29: error: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
comp.glsl:29: error: 'assign' :  l-value required (can't modify a const)
3 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:40: comp.spv] Error 1
$
```

For some reason it doesn't like the assignment to vert_typeOut[index]. If I comment that line out it compiles fine. Does glsl not like uints in shader storage buffers?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you accessing a everything as an array? None of the elements in your buffer are an array, and you're instead just indexing the elements of the vector, which of course doesn't work for a uint (or any other non vector/matrix type).

Comment: Because I am stumbling around with stuff I apparently don't yet quite understand. 8^) Anyway my root problem has been solved. The thing I learned in the process is that the base structure one uses to define arrays in these SSBOs needs to be 16 byte aligned. My app's vertex buffer was not so aligned, so when I defined the SSBO array to match the unaligned vertex buffer, the compiler added padding to the SSBO structure. When I added equivalent padding to the vertex buffer, all worked as expected. Thanks.